# Force Single Instance with Mutex handling restart application

Tags: .net, mutex, restart

I have a problem when i want use mutex to force single instance of my program.

I a winform App with a WebBrowser Control. I need to autorestart if certain conditions are met.

My Problem is that if i restart the application the mutex want let me open a new instance (this doesn't always happen) maybe cause browser has some async method like navigate.

But i release the Mutex in Exit Application Event.

This is my Code:

```
    static Mutex _mutex = new Mutex (false, "myprogramkey");

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    { 
         Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
      if(_mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), true))
      { 
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          Application.Run(new RevolutionForm()); 
      }

     else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Error!");
      }
    }
        static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single instance apps are well supported by the framework.  It supports goodies such as disabling it on-the-fly, what you need here, and getting a notification when another instance is started.  You'll want to use that to give your first instance the focus.  Rewrite your Program.cs code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;   // NOTE: add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    class Program : WindowsFormsApplicationBase {
        public Program() {
            EnableVisualStyles = true;
            MainForm = new Form1();
            IsSingleInstance = true;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Instance = new Program();
            Instance.Run(args);
        }
        protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs) {
            // Nicety, focus the single instance.
            Instance.MainForm.Activate();
        }
        public static void Restart() {
            // What you asked for.  Use Program.Restart() in your code
            Instance.IsSingleInstance = false;
            Application.Restart();
        }
        private static Program Instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hans I face the same issue as OP, but in my case my single instance inherit from `ApplicationContext` so it is not a `Form`, is there a way this can work with `ApplicationContext` ?

Comment: You'll have to click the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `try..finally` for managing the Mutex.
I usually use this approach. Worked well in combination with `Application.Restart()`.

```
    private const string ApplicationMutexName = "<myprogramkey>";

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        RunApplicationPreservingSingleInstance();
    }

    private static void RunApplicationPreservingSingleInstance()
    {
        Mutex mutex = AcquireMutex();
        if (mutex == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            RunApplication();
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private static Mutex AcquireMutex()
    {
        Mutex appGlobalMutex = new Mutex(false, ApplicationMutexName);
        if (!appGlobalMutex.WaitOne(3000))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return appGlobalMutex;
    }

    private static void RunApplication()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly goes wrong in your case but some issues might be:

- You should probably use `try finally` to close the mutex to maximize changes of proper cleanup
- In case cleanup failed previous time then `Mutex.WaitOne` will throw an `AbandonedMutexException` instead of return `true`. In this case your code will exit with an error box while you can just continue.
- You are giving the Mutex 5 seconds to get aquired. If your shutdown will take over 5 seconds then the next startup will fail. A better option might be to release mutex right before initiating shutdown. (Provided of course that the `Mutex` is there only for user convenience).

**example**

the following example will require that you use `Program.Restart` to restart the application. Else the time window can still be the problem.

```
static class Program
{
    private static Mutex _mutex;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        _mutex = new Mutex(false, "myprogramkey");
        try
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_mutex.WaitOne(1))
                {
                    _mutex.Dispose();
                    _mutex = null;
                    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException) { /* Mutex wasn't property released last time.*/ }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_mutex != null)
            {
                _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                _mutex.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Restart()
    {
        if (_mutex != null)
        {
            _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            _mutex.Dispose();
            _mutex = null;
            Application.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do:

```
    bool onlyInstance = false;
        mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "qFluid", out onlyInstance);
        int cntrSec = 0;
        //per far funzionare restart ,aspetto per 3 sec per vedere se va via servizio 
        while (!onlyInstance & cntrSec < 3)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            cntrSec += 1;
        }

        if (!onlyInstance)
        {
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("The application is already arunning");
            App.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: This preserve the mutex and stop second instance of  program : qFluid but it wait 3 seconds because i have do a button of restart :    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
Application.Current.Shutdown();